# Whether n tier architecture will slow down application performance

Tags: asp.net

When we are creating separate classes means (tiers) will take more time to traverse between pages.Whether this is the case?

I know there is many advantages for using the tiered architecture.Like easy to maintain,easy to understand.

What is actual scenario ?

Comment: This is never ever the bottleneck and you should not care about it. There are a million other things that "hurts" your performance more. Just think about how many objects are instantiated by the framework for each request anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply....ok...But i want to know is there any performance change between application with class and without class

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's a matter of under 1 ms in the response time. There are a lot of other stuff you can do to gain a lot more performance. If this is a problem you are using the wrong tool anyway and you'll need to use a more low level language where you have more control of how the computer executes your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, class will take performance hit as they will be destroyed by GC which in itself is a heavy operation.

Architecture is something which helps you achieve the business requirements with maximum capacity to scale. Now adding a tier in your application would definitely bring in a class, the object of which will be created and again after use, it will be destroyed by garbage collector. So there is a very thin line on what to use. You have to decide it according to your business and scalability.

Comment: thank you for reply...this means that there should be performance issue between application with classes and without classes......

Comment: If this has ever been a problem for you, the problem isn't that you had to many layers in you application, it's that you are using the wrong language and framework for the job. The GC will always run anyway. This simply isn't a problem in a website.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and destroying classes takes time, but in an OO language this is unavoidable.

As far as .NET is concerned it makes no difference, performance wise whether these classes are in the code behind files of ASP pages or in a separate library.

Comment: thank you for reply...this means that there shouldn't be performance issue between application with classes and without classes......

Comment: Indeed not. In fact in .NET almost everything is a class (all being based on Object)